# atmega2560 i2c problems

Tags: atmega, i2c, twi

I'm tying to use a atmega2560 but can't get the I2C working.
When I send the address byte i get never a ack response.
Does anyone see what i'm doing wrong i used the code out of the datasheet?
I tried it with a logic analyzer and it works so I do know the IC isn't defect.

```
void i2csend(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t data){
   TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN);
   while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
   if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != 0x08)//A  START  condition  has  been transmitted
   {
    stopi2c();
    return;
   }
   TWDR = addr;
   TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
   while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
   if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != 0x18)//SLA+W has been transmitted; 
                               ACK has been received
   {
    stopi2c();
    return;
   }    
   TWDR = reg;
   TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
   while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
   if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != 0x28)//Data  byte  has  been  transmitted; 
                               ACK has been received
   {
    stopi2c();
    return;
   }    
   TWDR = data;
   TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
   while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
   if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != 0x28)//Data  byte  has  been  transmitted; 
                               ACK has been received
   {
    stopi2c();
    return;
   }    
   stopi2c();
   return;
}
```

Comment: A possibly good test to make is to sweep all i2c addresses and see if you get any acks.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem when using I2C is to forget about shifting the slave address one bit to the left before using it.

An I2C address is just 7-bits left justified with the R/W bit at the bottom.

You don't say what the slave device is?  Are you sure the slave address is correct.

I haven't written i2c code for the atmega2560 but I have for other AVR family members.  The last one I did for an atmega328 I used the library from [Fleury I2C library](http://homepage.hispeed.ch/peterfleury/avr-software.html).

I found it useful to write an I2C scanner that would attempt to read from all i2c addresses and print out the ones where it received an ACK.

Comment: i'm using a pca9685 and here is the image from the datasheet i have connected the others to ground. so that is 0x40.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJNyD.png

Comment: Your code doesn't say what is the value of "addr"? I agree the SLA of your device is 0x40.  variable "addr" should be 0x80 when you left shift and or in the W bit. (0x81 for a read)

Comment: oh dam forgot about that